# FileTransferProgress refresh every x seconds WinSCP

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Is there a way to refresh the download/upload progress of a SFTP transfer in WinSCP? I know by default is updated every second, but for smaller files, it would be great to refresh every 100ms or so.

I am using this progress to update a console based progress bar.

I have my code as shown:

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
        session.FileTransferProgress += SessionFileTransferProgress;

        // Download/Upload code...
}
```

And the function itself:

```
void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
{
        //Basically draws a simple console based progress bar
        DrawProgressBar(e.FileProgress, 1, e.CPS); 
}
```

As mentioned, no problems with the code, it works fine. But it would be great to refresh my progress bar every less milliseconds.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to alter the interval.